# Is $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{H_n}{n}=\frac{6\ln^2(2)-\pi^2}{12}$ a valid identity?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers, dirichlet-series, conditional-convergence

A while ago I asked a question about an identity that I found while playing with series involving harmonic numbers. However, since the methods I used were not the focus of my question, I never explained how I got this result. So here it goes...

NOTE: It may be of help to work backwards through this problem instead. This is just how I did it.

We start by defining $H_n$ as the $n^{th}$ harmonic number.
We also take note of the identities:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n} = -\ln(2)$$
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Now we note that:

$$ \tag{1}H_n = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+n} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{n}{k(k+n)}$$

Since $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+n}$ is a telescoping series.

Dividing by $n$ we get:
$$\tag{2} \frac{H_n}{n} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k(k+n)}$$

Since $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n}$ is obviously divergent, I took a look at the alternating series:

$$ \tag{3}\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{H_n}{n} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k(k+n)}\right)$$

We must now multiply this series by 2 and add $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2} $ which is necessary for the next step.

So we have:

$$\begin{align}\tag{4}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2} + 2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k(k+n)}\right) & = \left(\frac{1}{1}\cdot\frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{3}+\cdots\right) \\ & -2 \left(\frac{1}{1}\cdot\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{4}+\cdots\right) 
\\ & +2 \left(\frac{1}{1}\cdot\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{5}+\cdots\right) 
\\ & -2 \left(\frac{1}{1}\cdot\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{6}+\cdots\right)
\\ & + \cdots \end{align}$$

With a very careful (and possibly illegal) rearrangement of this expanded sum, we can finally obtain: $\\$
(NOTE: It may be easier to work backwards through this step)

$$ \begin{align} \tag{5}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2} + 2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k(k+n)}\right) &= \left(-\frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3} + \cdots\right)\left(-\frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3} + \cdots\right)
\\ & = \ln^2(2)\end{align}$$

Thus, we have:

$$\tag{6}\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{H_n}{n} = \frac{6\ln^2(2) - \pi^2}{12} = -0.5822...$$

[Here](https://imgur.com/YC9n9Xa) are 3 graphs from computing the actual value of the sum. The first graph is of the difference between the actual sum and  $\frac{6*ln^2(2)-\pi^2}{12}$ for k up to 14000. As you can see it seems to converge on 0. You can ignore the 2nd and 3rd graphs.

QUESTIONS:

Is the method used from step 4-5 (or vise versa) legal even though it involves conditionally convergent series? If not, is there any restrictions and/or rearrangements I can use to make it legal?

Is there any known generalizations for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{H_n}{n^q}$ that extend this result?

Recommended readings that cover this topic would be greatly appreciated as well.

Thanks,
Dom

Comment: $H_n$ depends on n, so it cannot be a limit

Comment: I would use a generating functions approach:

It is well known that the harmonic numbers are generated by
$$
g(x)=-\frac{\log(1-x)}{1-x}=\sum_{n\geq 1} H_nx^n
$$

now denote the sum in question by $S$. It is easy to see that it can be obtained from the function

$$
S(x)=\int^x \frac{g(x')}{x'}dx=\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{H_n}{n}x^n
$$

via $S=S(-1)$

To calulate the integral we perform a partial fraction decompositon

$$
S(x)=-\int^x dx'\frac{\log(1-x')}{x'}-\int^x dx'\frac{\log(1-x')}{1-x'}
$$

...

Comment: ...the second integral is trivially integrated in terms of elementary functions yielding

$$
S(x)=-\int^x dx'\frac{\log(1-x')}{x'}+\frac{1}{2}\log(1-x)^2
$$

for the remaining integral we integrate the taylor series of $\log(1-x)/x$ term by term

$$
S(x)=\sum_{m\geq1}\frac{x^m}{m^2}+\frac{\log(1-x)^2}{2}
$$

and therfore

$$
S=S(-1)=\sum_{m\geq1}\frac{(-1)^m}{m^2}+\frac{\log^2(2)}{2}=\\
$$

or

>$$
S=\frac{\log(2)^2}{2}-\frac{\pi^2}{12}
$$

as announced

Comment: Thank you very much! If you make this response an answer I will certainly confirm it.

Comment: i think my comment is fine...i just want to mention that this also works for sums with higher powers of $n$ in the denominator.  for example 
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{H_n x^n}{n^2}=\int^x \frac{dx'}{x'} \int^{x'} \frac{dx''g(x'')}{x''}$$.

Comment: @tired: It's generally better to have answers (especially ratified ones) as answers rather than comments; it makes it easier for future visitors to see the whole story at once.

Comment: @tired Just a note: After looking at the duplicate thread, I found that your explanation was the shortest and easiest to follow. You should really consider making it an answer for others to see.